# Jekyll и Jekyll Build

Tags: ruby, jekyll, bundler

Решил поднять свой старенький блог на jekyll, обновил все гемы, бандлер и тд. 
Сейчас даже если просто написать в папке проект 'jekyll', то выдает вот это:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll- 
3.8.3/lib/jekyll/drops/document_drop.rb:8: 
warning: already initialized constant 
Jekyll::Drops::DocumentDrop::NESTED_OBJECT_FIELD_BLACKLIST
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/drops/document_drop.rb:8: warning: 
previous definition of NESTED_OBJECT_FIELD_BLACKLIST was here
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.3/lib/jekyll/drops/drop.rb:8: 
warning: already initialized constant 
Jekyll::Drops::Drop::NON_CONTENT_METHODS
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/drops/drop.rb:8: warning: previous 
definition of NON_CONTENT_METHODS was here
```

Если написать jekyll build, то вот такое:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.3/lib/jekyll/drops/document_drop.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant Jekyll::Drops::DocumentDrop::NESTED_OBJECT_FIELD_BLACKLIST
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/drops/document_drop.rb:8: warning: previous definition of NESTED_OBJECT_FIELD_BLACKLIST was here
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.3/lib/jekyll/drops/drop.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant Jekyll::Drops::Drop::NON_CONTENT_METHODS
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/drops/drop.rb:8: warning: previous definition of NON_CONTENT_METHODS was here
Configuration file: /home/sayo/sayobye_blog/sayobye.github.io/_config.yml
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/csv.rb:211: warning: already initialized constant CSV::VERSION
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/csv-3.0.0/lib/csv/version.rb:5: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/csv.rb:925: warning: already initialized constant CSV::FieldInfo
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/csv-3.0.0/lib/csv.rb:301: warning: previous definition of FieldInfo was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/csv.rb:928: warning: already initialized constant CSV::DateMatcher
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/csv-3.0.0/lib/csv.rb:304: warning: previous definition of DateMatcher was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/csv.rb:931: warning: already initialized constant CSV::DateTimeMatcher
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/csv-3.0.0/lib/csv.rb:307: warning: previous definition of DateTimeMatcher was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/csv.rb:936: warning: already initialized constant CSV::ConverterEncoding
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/csv-3.0.0/lib/csv.rb:316: warning: previous definition of ConverterEncoding was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/csv.rb:962: warning: already initialized constant CSV::Converters
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/csv-3.0.0/lib/csv.rb:342: warning: previous definition of Converters was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/csv.rb:1010: warning: already initialized constant CSV::HeaderConverters
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/csv-3.0.0/lib/csv.rb:390: warning: previous definition of HeaderConverters was here
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/csv.rb:1035: warning: already initialized constant CSV::DEFAULT_OPTIONS
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/csv-3.0.0/lib/csv.rb:415: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_OPTIONS was here
            Source: /home/sayo/sayobye_blog/sayobye.github.io
       Destination: /home/sayo/sayobye_blog/sayobye.github.io/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
             ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
                    ------------------------------------
                    Key related_posts cannot be set in the drop.
```

Подскажите как фиксить, раньше работало нормально, конфиги никакие не менял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена переустановкой bundle без sudo.